# Devise password reset issue (new_user?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

When a user's email is inputted into the forgot password form and submitted, I am receiving an error saying `login can't be blank`.  I looked around `devise.en.yml` for this error message, but can't seem to find it anywhere.

Here is my `views/devise/passwords/new.html.haml`:

```
%div.registration_page
  %h2 Forgot your password?
  = form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_password_path, :html => { :method => :post, :id => 'forgot_pw_form', :class => 'forgot_pw' }) do |f|
    %div
      = f.email_field :email, :placeholder => 'Email', :autofocus => true, :autocomplete => 'off'
      %div.email_error.error
    %input.btn.btn-success{:type => 'submit', :value => 'Send Instructions'}
  = render "devise/shared/links"
```

The form is posting to `users/password` like it should, but I noticed that my forgot password form attaches `class = 'new_user'`.  Here is what my form displays:

```
<form accept-charset='UTF-8' action='/users/password' class='new_user' id='forgot_pw_form' method='post' novalidate='novalidate'></form>
```

My routes for devise (I have custom sessions and registrations controllers):

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => 'sessions', :registrations => 'registrations'}
```

How can I setup devise's forgot password functionality? Why am I receiving this error message and why is that class being added there?

I've tried:

- Adding my own passwords controller and adding new routes for my custom controller. Same error
- Adding my own class and id to the form.  This successfully changes the id and class of the form, but reverts back to class and id of `new_user`

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this issue also. I was missing the _method tag so it was routing to password#create instead of password#update

If it is the same issue, the following in your form will get you going:

```html
 <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
```

Comment: This was my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think your main issue can be one of the following:

1) Your routes doesn't look correctly set up it should look something like this

```
   devise_for :users, :controllers => {:sessions => 'devise/sessions', :registrations => 'devise/registrations', :passwords => 'devise/passwords'}, :skip => [:sessions] do
```

2) Your **passwords/new.html.erb** looks a bit incorrect try this:

```
<h2>Forgot your password?</h2>

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => password_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :post }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email %></div>

  <div><%= f.submit "Send me reset password instructions" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

3) Inside your inside your config/environments/development.rb do the following:

**Development.rb**

```
#Defined SMTP options
  #config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "77.100.90.77:3000"
  #SMTP
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000/' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => 'gmail.com',
      :user_name            => '*****@gmail.com',
      :password             => 'PASS',
      :authentication       => 'login',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

You can see from this set up I am using gmail for testing purposes. Following what I have provided should resolve your issue. Let me know if this works.

**Update**

would presume that authentication_keys set :username as a required field.

Try editing app/views/devise/passwords/new.html.erb, and replacing:

```
<%= f.label :email %>
<br />
<%= f.text_field :email %>
```

with:

```
<%= f.label :username %>
<br />
<%= f.text_field :username %>
```

Comment: My routes seem to be set up correctly. I have custom `session` and `registration` controllers (named `sessions_controller.rb` and `registrations_controller.rb` respectively). My smtp options are also set up exactly like you specified. When I input an email into the form, I get an alert saying `login can't be blank.` I don't know why this error is popping up when the only input element is the email field.

Comment: Have you also checked in initaliziers/devise.rb that you have enabled `config.authentication_keys = [ :email ]`

Comment: Yes, I did. I found out my stupid mistake. `f.email_field :login` instead of `f.email_field :email`. I enabled login with emails AND usernames, which is why I kept getting that error. Shoot me.